# Logic Apps Do Until SharePoint Library

Tags: sharepoint, azure-logic-apps

I am trying to update a property for a library item in SharePoint using logic apps, using the Do/Until action. I'm running a graph call that updates one of the fields. If it fails, a delay for 4 minutes kicks in. If it doesn't fail, a variable is set to true, meeting the Until condition. However, it's not working and runs forever. In Power Automate, this works. But Logic Apps, not so much. I have seen some posts here with the Logic Apps do until action however the graphic included does not match what is available to me so I'm assuming it is not the same issue. I am able to perform this in Power Automate but when I try to do it in Logic Apps it just keeps on running and running with no outcome. I'm using the Delay action to try the HTTP call after 2 minutes. If the HTTP call succeeds, the variable is set to true and the Until portion should kick in. However, it looks like the Until portion has a count and timeout. I'm not sure why I need those since I have a Delay. But right now, not sure what to set it to. I'm more concerned about the Delay. In Power Automate, this action is very easy to set.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you share your workflow, at least some screenshots?

Comment: Workflow design screenshots of both logic apps and power apps would be helpful to understand your issue clearly

Comment: Can you share the endpoint you are using in Http trigger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have used delay when it fails, you should not use parallel action and below is the design:

[image]

If action fails then set it to fail:

[image]

[image]

and it did worked for me:

[image]